# create a distance look up table within a graph with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have objects with ids and connection objects which hold the id of element a and the id of element b.

```
function Item(){
   this.id = id;
}

function Line(startId, targetId){
   this.startId = startId;
   this.targetId = targetId;
}


const lines = [
    new Line(1, 2),
    new Line(2, 3),
    new Line(2, 4),
    new Line(2, 7),
    new Line(3, 5),
    new Line(4, 6),
    new Line(5, 2),
    new Line(7, 3),
    new Line(7, 4),
];
```

I want to create a look up table for the item X means I want to calculate the distance to reach item X from the current item.

[image: img]

The result for the *itemId 1* would be something like this

item | depth

1  |  0
  2  |  1
  3  |  2
  4  |  2
  5  |  3
  6  |  3
  7  |  3

I started creating this algorithm

```
getLookUpTable(targetId){
    const lookUpTable = [];
    let openList = this.lines;

    this.checkTableItems(openList, targetId, 0, lookUpTable);

    return lookUpTable;
}

checkTableItems(openList, currentTargetId, currentLevel, lookUpTable){
    while (openList.length > 0) {
        currentLevel++;

        const targetLines = this.getLinesByTargetId(currentTargetId, openList);

        targetLines.forEach(line => {
            this.addLineToTable(line, currentTargetId, lookUpTable, currentLevel, openList);
        });
    }
}

addLineToTable(line, currentTargetId, lookUpTable, currentLevel, openList){
    const itemId = line.targetId == currentTargetId ? line.startId : activity.toId;
    this.addTableItem(lookUpTable, itemId, currentLevel);
    this.checkTableItems(openList, itemId, currentLevel, lookUpTable);
}

getLinesByTargetId(currentTargetId, openList){
    const targetLines = this.getTargetLines(currentTargetId, openList);
    openList = this.removeTargetLines(currentTargetId, openList);
    return targetLines;
}

getTargetLines(currentTargetId, openList){
    return openList.filter(x => x.startId == currentTargetId || x.targetId == currentTargetId);
}

removeTargetLines(currentTargetId, openList){
    return openList.filter(x => x.startId != currentTargetId && x.targetId != currentTargetId);
}

addTableItem(lookUpTable, id, cost){
    lookUpTable.push({
        id: id,
        cost: cost
    });
}
```

but I run into a stack overflow because the lookup table grows bigger and bigger.

How can I make this loop recursive that all elements get examined correctly for their depth relative to the target item?

Comment: I guess you should keep another list of "open nodes", so that you can check if any of the elements is connected to that at the second / third / fourth iteration

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach: turn the list of lines into a tree of nodes that reference each other. Then go down that tree recursively and add the depth of the node if it has not already been visited, otherwise end here to prevent infinite loops:

```
// Build the tree:

const items = {};

for(const {startId, targetId} of lines) {
  if(!items[startId]) items[startId] = { id: startId, next: [] };
  if(!items[targetId]) items[targetId] = { id: targetId, next: [] };
  items[startId].next.push(items[targetId]);
}

// Get the depth:
function addDepth(node, depth) {
  if(node.depth) return;
  node.depth = depth;
  node.next.forEach(node => addDepth(node, depth + 1));
}
addDepth(items[1], 1)
```

Comment: sorry, I think this code is really nice but I don't understand it very well. I thought there would be a simpler solution

Comment: @matthias its actually quite simple, what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: to me, it is easy to read, I tried to create my own version but I run into a stackoverflow, I will update my answer but the short version is here  https://pastebin.com/JMrNS69y